# List User order by ID in Descending order (Backend)

Tags: php, wp-admin, admin, query, users

I'm  trying to Show User List in WordPress Admin in Descending order by "ID" column.

I tried below code

```
add_action('pre_user_search', 'change_user_order');

function change_user_order($query)
{
    $query->query_orderby = ' ORDER BY ID DESC';
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: Note that action `pre_user_search` is among deprecated functions. Perhaps you should try `pre_user_query `.

Comment: @toni_lehtimaki i tried changing it to `pre_user_query` still its not working

Comment: I changed my suggestion to `pre_get_users` and made an answer for it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I first thought that `pre_user_query` would be that hook for the job. But I think using the equivalent of `pre_get_posts`, which is [`pre_get_users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_users/), would be suitable here.

You also said you wanted to run this in admin. So we will check that before running this.

```
function my_custom_order_users_by_id( $query ) {

   //Check that we are in admin otherwise return
   if( !is_admin() ) {
      return;
   }

   // We are changing the query_vars to reorder
   $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'ID';
   $query->query_vars['order']   = 'DESC';

   // We need to remember to return the altered query.
   return $query;
}
// Lets apply our function to hook.
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'my_custom_order_users_by_id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As per user @toni_lehtimaki **pre_user_search** is deprecated. Below code is working.

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'change_user_order');

function change_user_order($query) {

    $query->query_orderby = ' ORDER BY ID DESC';
}
```

Comment: i tried this function as it is but its not working..!!

Comment: where should I use this function? function.php or user.php?

Comment: In function.php file of your current activated theme

Comment: its changing URL query, i want to show User Detail table in descending order by ID